# Centering Badge Along Top Edge Of Card Component

Tags: html, css

I have a card component (the larger rectangle) and am hoping to have a badge (the smaller rectangle) positioned as seen in the image

Any thoughts on best approach?

[image]

*(Have been attempting to leverage absolute positioning but having trouble coming up with a way to get it centered)*

Comment: Grid maybe? I feel like CSS Grid makes it easy to overlap and position elements

Comment: @chase a `CSS-Grid` is the completely wrong sue for this purpose. You dont want to aling all child elements just re-align a single title. `fieldset` + `legend` will do that already by default as my 2nd example shows

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then to center absolutely placed elements, use the combination `left: 50%;` and `transform: translateX(-50%);`. Example below:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 60px; /* just for a better look at the example */
}

.top-badge {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border: 3px solid black;
  background: whitesmoke;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top-badge">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `fieldset` and `legend` which will do that by default. You just have to center the legend by using `margin: 0 auto`:

```css
legend {
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* for visualization only */
fieldset {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

legend {
  display: block;
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
}

fieldset, legend {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend></legend>
</fieldset>
```

Alterntivly you can also use `position: relative`+ `position: absolute`:

```
.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

which will center it perfectly vertically 50% of the titles height and horizontally in the exact center:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* for visualization only */
.box {
  height: 60vh;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-top: 20vh;
}

.title {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with the first solution you presented is that unless there is a form in the element, the ```<fieldset>``` it is not being used properly from a semantics point of view. Fieldsets are used to group controls and labels within a form. If there is no form, you shouldn't use a fieldset. Your other solution is spot on.